# Dynamic filter array based on array of conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is there a way to filter an array using jQuery-QueryBuilder? The plugin generates an array of conditions like this:

```
condition:"OR"
rules: {
    field:"name"
    id:"name"
    input:"select"
    operator:"equal"
    type:"string"
    value:"Albert"
}
```

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var user = [{
    personal: {
        email: ''
        age: 30
    }
    code: 1396664
    name: 'Albert'
}, {
   personal: {
        email: ''
        age: 35
    }
    code: 1234123
    name: 'Taylor'
}]
```

Comment: The Json is wrong `rules` should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

There's no build in functionality for this sorry. You'll have to implement it yourself depending on **how** your array is built

But you can have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/453) where someone is providing some sort of solution... In a GIF ...

Answer (score 0):

The way you're asking I've never seen any native Jquery solution, maybe there's some plugin to make this. However, you can do that creating functions with the conditions and passing them to the Jquery method grep:

```
var user = [{
    personal: {
        email: '',
        age: 30
    },
    code: 1396664,
    name: 'Albert'
}, {
   personal: {
        email: '',
        age: 35
    },
    code: 1234123,
    name: 'Taylor'
}, {
   personal: {
        email: '',
        age: 41
    },
    code: 9999999,
    name: 'John'
}];

var filter1 = function(value, index){
    return value.name == 'Albert' || value.personal.age > 40;
};

var filter2 = function(value, index){
    return value.name == 'Taylor';
};

arr = jQuery.grep(user, filter1);
arr2 = jQuery.grep(user, filter2);

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
```

The example is [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/oe1jns6y/)